# AWS ECS Policy: Lock down permissions to services depending on owner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm pretty new to AWS so please bear with me.

I currently have this `ecs.yaml`:

```
...
ECSSendMessageToSQSRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
            - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
        Action: sts:AssumeRole
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: ecs-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - ssm:*
                - s3:*
              Resource: '*'
```

As you can see, the Policy allows our role to access ALL S3 buckets and ALL SSM functionality.

I would like to change the permissions in such a way that:

- S3 Buckets: All actions allowed if we own the bucket.
- SSM: just allow a certain action called `GetParameter`, for example.

Any orientation on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - ssm:GetParameter
          Resource: '*'
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - s3:*
          Resource: 
            - 'arn:aws:s3:::the-bucket'
            - 'arn:aws:s3:::the-bucket/*'
```

Check out the [S3 ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-s3) docs for more details on ARN format.

Hope that helps :)